# Unity: How to make multiple agents circle the building when I click to atk it in my rts game

Tags: unity-game-engine, agent, navmesh

I have tried to initiate several point arround the building to attack. but this way is not flexible enough, like the agents may have different radius, therefore the attack point shouldn't be that even.

have any good ideas?

Answer (score 0):

They should flock/swarm. Basically: agents should go to their nearest attack position while keeping a distance form any friendly agent.

Comment: like this http://farm1.staticflickr.com/287/20273028172_0971792675_b.jpg    how to make to agents encircle the building when atk it